# Saving a form created from a directive dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´ve just created two nested directives, wich the first one shares the data requested from a services in the controller, that helps me to first load the data and pass it to the nested directive to build a form in a dynamic way, then I have a controller, in wich I delcared the `$scope.model = {}`, to be used as a model and obtain the values of each dynamic form, so I need to save those data from a dynamic form, I just added in the input the ng-model as it the examples in the angularjs site says, `ng-model="model.field_name"` but when I look for the object in my controller it didn´t updated and I just see a empty object.

I´m doing something wrong or I missing something.

P.S: I´m using `jqlite` to append the elements in the form and used the   `$compile(elem.contents())(scope);` statement to bind all the directives in the element.

For a more clear understand I've just created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rubenG/LWQ4M/9/

Comment: add your directive code.is you directive using isolated scope?

Comment: Please write your code for understand better. And remember that for forms and $scope comunication you must use the ng-model directive.

Comment: Can we have code snippet?It's hard to understand

Comment: Yes, it´s on a isolate scope @pankajparkar and I´m working for a plunker to show what I´m talking thanks for the quik answers!

Comment: The post is updated, with the jsfiddle demo. @rigobcastro.

Comment: Ok, Can you use an array instead of object for parse model data?